# how can git post-receive hook get name of repo it is running on?

Tags: git

I have a git post receive hook that will trigger a build on my build system.
I need to create a string of the form "$repo-name + $branch" in the hook script.

I can parse the branch, but how can I get the repository name from git?

Thanks!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The "repository name" isn't a well-defined idea in git, I think.  Perhaps what would be most useful is to return `whatever.git` in the case of a bare repository or `whatever` in the case of a repository with a working tree.  I've tested that this bit of Bourne shell deals with both cases properly from within a `post-receive` hook:

```
if [ $(git rev-parse --is-bare-repository) = true ]
then
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD") 
else
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename $(readlink -nf "$PWD"/..))
fi
echo REPOSITORY_BASENAME is $REPOSITORY_BASENAME
```

*Update:* if you want to remove the `.git` extension in the bare repository case, you could add a line to the first case to strip it off:

```
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=$(basename "$PWD")
    REPOSITORY_BASENAME=${REPOSITORY_BASENAME%.git}
```

Comment: Great. That works. How can I remove the ".git" from a bare repo?

Answer (score 1):

You can inspect $GIT_DIR, or $GIT_WORK_TREE and get the repo name from there.

Comment: `GIT_DIR` is just set to `.` and `GIT_WORK_TREE` isn't set in the environment for hooks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`, which will give you the path of the top-level directory, and pull the name out of that (reponame.git is conventional for remotely-accessible repos).

`$PWD` might also have the same information, but I'm unsure.

Comment: `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` won't work in a bare repository.  (`$PWD` will be the top level of the working tree for a repository with a working tree, or the repository directory itself for a bare repository, so you need to do a little more work to get a helpful name...)

Answer (score 0):

If one is using [Gitolite](http://gitolite.com/), the `GL_REPO` variable is available in the `post-receive` environment by default.