# How to find the path of the local git repository when I am possibly in a subdirectory

Tags: git, path, environment

I'm looking for something like `git list-path` printing the
path of the associated repository (the `.git` directory).

A bit of background: I have set up git version control on quite a few of my
projects/folders.  Some of them are nested, so one directory with echo own repository is a subfolder to another directory tracked with another repository.

E.g. in my home directory (`~`) I use git to track my dot files, but
in folder `~/photo/meta-mix/` I have another project I track with a
separate repository. Now, say,I have set up another project in directory
`~/photo/meta-match/`, but I don't know anymore whether it has its own
repository. So I want to find out whether this directory is version
controlled and where its repository is.

How can I do this with a git command? `git status` can give me

```
nothing to commit
```

in *both* cases, when `~/photo/meta-match/` has its own repository or when it just refers to the repository of `~`.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

could be enough if executed within a git repo.
From [`git rev-parse`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse) man page:

```
--show-toplevel
```

> Show the absolute path of the top-level directory.

For older versions (before 1.7.x), the other options are listed in "[Is there a way to get the git root directory in one command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/957928/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-git-root-directory-in-one-command)":

```
git rev-parse --git-dir
```

That would give the path of the `.git` directory.

---

The OP mentions:

```
git rev-parse --show-prefix
```

which returns the local path under the git repo root. (empty if you are at the git repo root)

---

Note: for simply checking if one is in a git repo, I find the following command quite expressive:

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree
```

And yes, if you need to check if you are in a `.git` git-dir folder:

```
git rev-parse --is-inside-git-dir
```

Comment: Unfortunately on older versions of `git` (before v1.7.0) that just prints `--show-toplevel` -- it's not even an error.

Comment: @BenJackson any chance to upgrade? If not, I have edited to add another command

Comment: Not my question:  I'm just commenting on the answer.  Given the old behavior I can see real confusion if someone released a script relying on that method.

Comment: @BenJackson Ok, I have added another option.

Comment: Reading up on `rev-parse` I found another good one in this regards: `git rev-parse --show-prefix`: it is empty when I here have a git repository.

Comment: @halloleo: Interesting. I have added it to the answer for more visibility. I have also added more commands about simply checking if one is in a git repo.

Comment: git rev-parse --show-toplevel is empty if I run it from bare repository. It gives me absolute path perfectly fine from a non-bare repo. Any reasons as to why it might be happening? @VonC

Comment: @MudassirRazvi because it expects a working tree, and bare repos have none. For bare repo top folder, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/5584084/6309.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted! I am also writing a post-receive hook! You Save lives @VonC as always! :)

Comment: @MudassirRazvi Well..., in this instance, Mark Longair did save lives (http://stackoverflow.com/users/223092/mark-longair) ;)

Comment: Even on newer versions of git (I have 2.30.1), typing something invalid here doesn't give you an error. I mistakenly entered `--show-top-level` instead of `--show-toplevel` and just got "--show-top-level" as output, which was confusing. Type your commands correctly!