# Deploying to Different Web Servers via Git

Tags: git, deployment, workflow, githooks

Is it possible (and if so, is it good practice) for a remote Git repository to deploy to multiple web servers (e.g., a staging server and production server) depending upon branch name? For example, if developer A pushes a commit to remote branch `STAGING`, the commit is deployed to the corresponding staging web server, whereas commits (or merges) to branch `MASTER` are deployed to the production server.

Does this illustrate a good/reliable workflow? If not, what is a better approach?

[image: Git workflow example]

Comment: what method are you using to deploy on a single server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I have seen that done before (like in my [previous answer from 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11323004/6309))

To [get the branch name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29959913/6309), use:

```
branch=$(git rev-parse --symbolic --abbrev-ref $refname)
```

Then you can push to the right server

```
  if [ "master" == "$branch" ]; then
    git push production
    echo 'Changes pushed live.'
  fi

  if [ "staging" == "$branch" ]; then
    git push staging
    echo 'Changes pushed to staging.'
  fi
```

That assume two remotes each one referencing a remote bare repo.
The destination bare repo would have a `post-receive` hook with:

```
git --work-tree=/path/under/root/dir/site/ checkout -f $branch
```